# sql creates two tables using $wpdb->prefix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

```
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "name";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename(
    time_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    job VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    employee VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    date_entry DATETIME NOT NULL,
    duration INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(time_id)
);";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

dbDelta($sql);
```

creates two tables: 'wp_name' and 'name'. If I define $tablename = 'wp_name' instead it only creates one table. Also '{$wpdb->prefix}name' doesn't change the problem.

What's the problem here? - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get rd of the brackets

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (
    ...
);";
```

They are only used to replace internal wp variables

**Update:**

your case can't create two tables by itself, there is no way, you have somewhere the same code twice.

Without the prefix, the second code checks that there is already a table named `name`and does nothing, but when you add the prefix, it  tries to add the tbale `name` which azt this time doesn't exist, because it is call `wp_name`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't change it. Still two tables ...

Comment: please post the hole code of your create tables. Also check if mutti query is enabled, else make two queries as it seems that wordpress don't support multi queries see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305116

Comment: ok the code for this table works, and where is your second? for the time being you should enable error log in wordpress see https://brightbrightgreat.com/2016/03/24/how-to-log-mysql-errors-in-wordpress/

Comment: you have the **twice** somewhere, see changed answer

Comment: no sesond one. This seems the code that generates both tables. If I change to e.g. $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'example' I get the two tables 'wp_example' and 'example'

Comment: When you run your code without prefix, enable genral log for mysql and you will see **two comands with the same content, if you add the prefix you see bith comands again but thos time with two diffrent table names, so the code runs **twice** for my part, i would search the hole folder for soem partt of the crete table and see where it is hiding, or fiond where the loop is.